# How to prevent "+" from escaping in go-echo

Tags: go, go-echo

I am using https://github.com/labstack/echo in one of the projects. I am using `c.QueryParam` to parse the query parameter and its values. One of the values contains a `+` symbol in it and it converts them to a space character (which is correct). However, I would like to retain the `+` character in the value.

Ex: `http://localhost:8080?param=test+test`

```
fmt.Println(c.QueryParam("param"))
```

Right now it outputs `test test`. However, I am expecting the output as `test+test`. Is it possible to achieve it using `c.QueryParam`?

Comment: Why don't you just encode params with plus sign? ex:`test%2Btest`

Comment: `strings.Replace(c.QueryParam("param"), " ", "+", -1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom helper function like below -

```
func CustomQueryParam(c echo.Context, name string) string {
    qParams := make(map[string]string)
    for _, singleQueryParamStr := range strings.Split(c.QueryString(), "&") {
        val := strings.Split(singleQueryParamStr, "=")
        qParams[val[0]] = val[1]
    }
    return qParams[name]
}

func TestGet(c echo.Context) error {
    param := CustomQueryParam(c, "param")
    fmt.Println(param)

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, map[string]interface{}{
        "message": "request is successful",
    })
}
```

Now, the output is as your expection. It prints `test+test`. But what actually `CustomQueryParam` do?

Okay, let's explore the insight. Suppose, the api call is -

`http://localhost:8080?param=test1+test2&param2=test3`

The `CustomQueryParam` function will take an `echo.Context` instance and the query param name as function parameters.

Then, inside for loop the whole query string i.e. in our case which is `param=test1+test2&param2=test3` is split by `&` and stored into string slice made by each query param string (`[]string{"param=test1+test2", "param2=test3"}`).

After that, we iterate over each query param string and again split into a string slice of two values having first value as param name and second value as param value. For example, for first query param string, the resultant output is like below -

`"param=test1+test2"` => `[]string{"param", "test1+test2"}`

Then, the first value (param name) is assigned as map key and second value (param value) as map value.

After finishing above process for every query string, the map value by query param name (which is the parameter of this function) is returned.

One of the interesting fact about this custom function is that it returns empty string if query param is not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the raw query and then parse the parameter and it's value

```golang
func hello(c echo.Context) error {
    //to get the raw query
    fmt.Println(c.Request().URL.RawQuery)
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
}
```

Then you can use `strings.split(rawQuery,"=")` to get the parameter and it's value.